# How to fix a stack overflow in my java program?

Tags: java

So, I am studying java, and as a first exercise I decided to write two small and composable functions, namely a fibbonacci and a factorial function, which have a common implementation detail, however I received a stack overflow exception when I tried to separate their common part into a separate function. Any tips on what am I doing wrong?

```
public class BaseFunctions{

    static Integer factorial(Integer num) {

        return factorial(comComponent(num)-1)*num;

    }

    static Integer fibbonacci(Integer num) {

     return fibbonacci(comComponent(num)-1) + fibbonacci(comComponent(num)-2);
    }       

    static Integer comComponent(Integer num) {

        if(num == 1 || num == 0) {
            return 1;

        }else if(num < 0){

            throw new ArithmeticException("Num must be > 0");

        }else return num;

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you basically never get of out of the "fibonacci" method.

Comment: See https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Fibonacci.java.html for an example.

Answer (score 2):

When you reach `num = 0`, `comComponent` will return 1, calling your function with `num = 0` again, thus getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive function must have an **exit point** (which must be checked first before any recursive call), if not this leads to **Stack Overflow**. 
What you do is leave the function without that exit point, be delegating (or so you think) this functionality to `comComponent()`. 
But take a look at the code inside `factorial()`:

```
return factorial(comComponent(num)-1)*num;
```

Why should it ever stop? There is no `return` statement without a recursive call.
So your logic is wrong. 
Drop `comComponent()` and stick to the traditional way:

```
static Integer factorial(Integer num) {
    if (num == 1 || num == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (num < 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Num must be > 0");
    else
        return factorial(num - 1) * num;
}

static Integer fibbonacci(Integer num) {
    if (num == 1 || num == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (num < 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Num must be > 0");
    else
        return fibbonacci(num - 1) + fibbonacci(num - 2);
}
```

As you can see both functions have an exit point:

```
if (num == 1 || num == 0)
    return 1;
```